# EF Core code first migration: "The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm doing a code first migration to my PostgreSQL database. I've configured my relationships according to some examples I've seen, but I'm getting stumped on the error below.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'ecommercecontent.identification' and 'ecommercecontentidentification.ecommercecontent'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.

My code samples are below, with some things stripped out for brevity.

Here are the two classes in question:

```
public class ecommercecontent
{
    [Key]
    public int ecommercecontentid { get; set; }

    public string productnameenglish { get; set; }

    public string productnamefrench { get; set; }

    public string brandnameenglish { get; set; }

    public string brandnamefrench { get; set; }

    public ecommercecontentidentification identification { get; set; }
}

public class ecommercecontentidentification
{
    [Key]
    public int ecommercecontentidentificationid { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset archivedate { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset dateupdated { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset startdate { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset systemversion { get; set; }

    public ecommercecontent ecommercecontent { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `DbContext` class with the `OnModelCreating` override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ecommercecontent>()
        .HasOne(a => a.identification)
        .WithOne(b => b.ecommercecontent)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You can define `.HasOne(...).WithOne(...)` starting from either side of the relationship. It's `.HasForeignKey<T>(...)` that tells the fluent api which is the primary and which is the dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a one-to-one relationship, you need to tell EF which is the dependent. For example, if `ecommercecontentidentification` is the dependent, then you need to add this line.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ecommercecontent>()
        .HasOne(a => a.identification)
        .WithOne(b => b.ecommercecontent)
        .HasForeignKey<ecommercecontentidentification>(e => e.{{foriegn key property}})
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I don't know what key is shared between these two tables. Your `ecommercecontentidentification` needs to have the `ecommercecontentid` on it or vice-versa.

Comment: That did the trick. I followed your suggestion and added the new field (ecommercecontentidentification.ecommercecontentid), and then used the HasForeignKey method to select that new field as the foreign key.